# Join tables in Django using common foreign key

Tags: django-models, join, foreign-keys

I'd like to join tables that don't have a direct relationship, but that share a foreign key relationship.

Here's an example set of models:

```
class Community(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Event(models.Model):
    type = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class PersonEvent(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Review(models.Model):
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    last_review = models.DateTimeField()
```

And here's the SQL for the query that I'd like to do:

```
SELECT * FROM community_event E
  INNER JOIN community_personevent PE ON (E.id = PE.event_id)
  INNER JOIN community_review R USING (person_id)
  WHERE E.timestamp > R.last_review;
```

Then here's some example data:

```
big = Community(name="Big")
big.save()
little = Community(name="Little")
little.save()

bill = Person(name="Bill")
bill.save()
bill = Person(name="Bill")
bill.save()
james = Person(name="James") 
james.save()
sally = Person(name="Sally") 
sally.save()

event_a = Event(type=1, timestamp='2020-01-02T03:04:05+00')
event_a.save()
event_b = Event(type=1, timestamp='2020-01-02T03:04:06+00')
event_b.save()
event_c = Event(type=2, timestamp='2020-01-02T03:04:06+00')
event_c.save()
event_d = Event(type=2, timestamp='2020-01-02T03:04:07+00')
event_d.save()

personevent_a = PersonEvent(person=bill, event=event_a)
personevent_a.save()
personevent_b = PersonEvent(person=james, event=event_b)
personevent_b.save()
personevent_bill_b = PersonEvent(person=bill, event=event_b)
personevent_bill_b.save()
personevent_sally_c = PersonEvent(person=sally, event=event_c)
personevent_sally_c.save()
personevent_sally_d = PersonEvent(person=sally, event=event_d)
personevent_sally_d.save()
personevent_james_d = PersonEvent(person=james, event=event_d)
personevent_james_d.save()

review_big_bill = Review(community=big, person=bill, last_review = '2020-01-02T03:04:06+00')
review_big_bill.save()
review_big_james = Review(community=big, person=james, last_review = '2020-01-02T03:04:05+00')
review_big_james.save()
review_little_sally = Review(community=little, person=sally, last_review = '2020-01-02T03:04:05+00')
review_little_sally.save()
review_little_james = Review(community=little, person=james, last_review = '2020-01-02T03:04:06+00')
review_little_james.save()
```

And the expected result from the SQL query and the corresponding Django query would be the following:

```
2|1|2020-01-02 03:04:06|2|2|3|2|2020-01-02 03:04:05|1
3|2|2020-01-02 03:04:06|4|3|4|3|2020-01-02 03:04:05|2
4|2|2020-01-02 03:04:07|5|4|4|3|2020-01-02 03:04:05|2
4|2|2020-01-02 03:04:07|6|4|3|2|2020-01-02 03:04:05|1
4|2|2020-01-02 03:04:07|6|4|3|4|2020-01-02 03:04:06|2
```